# ¿Cuál es el significado de "robar la cartera" en este contexto?

Tags: significado, modismos, significado-en-contexto, deportes

He encontrado el siguiente titular de deportes: "Hamilton le **roba la cartera** a Verstappen y Alonso saldrá octavo en Hungría", que es desarrollado como:

> Lewis Hamilton saldrá primero en el Gran Premio de Hungría de Fórmula 1 al aventajar por tan solo tres milésimas a Max Verstappen. El británico le **robó la cartera** al holandés en el último suspiro de la sesión de clasificación y conquistó la novena ‘pole’ de su carrera en Hungaroring tras una espera de casi dos años...

Por el contexto está claro que no hacen referencia a un robo de cartera en sentido literal, pero no queda claro el significado alegórico.

Comment: Just for interest the English idiom is "He picked his pocket" although it is not that common a phrase.

Comment: took him to the cleaners

Answer (score 3):

Muchos términos o frases empleados por los periodistas deportivos provienen de los que habitualmente se utilizan en fútbol. En ocasiones, al referirse a un regate, suelen emplear "robar la cartera" por lo sorpresivo, repentino e inesperado de la acción, apenas percibida o no por el perjudicado.

Aplicado al automovilismo, si un corredor consigue una ventaja ante la confianza de otro que se cree ganador, puede ser una acción tan sorpresiva, improvista e inesperada como un regate, como un robo de cartera.

Answer (score 3):

Por añadir algo más a la respuesta de Danielillo, el carterismo es una acción que en el imaginario popular requiere una gran habilidad, ya que supone que te roben sin que te des ni cuenta.

Por tanto, esta acepción se aplica perfectamente en situaciones en las que alguien, con gran maña y habilidad, es capaz de superar a un rival en una situación, casi sin que el otro sea capaz de darse ni cuenta.

De este modo, la expresión traslada varias ideas sobre la maestría de la acción en apenas tres palabras.